# Binding listbox content to another listbox

Tags: c#

I have 2 listboxes in my form and I binded some data to first listbox from the database. Now I have to show the selected items of the first listbox in the second listbox when a buton is pressed. im able to show one selected item at a time, but im unable to show multiple selected items. I used a hash table and the follwing code please help me im new to this concept thank in advance.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add(listbox1.SelectedValue.ToString(),listbox1.Text.ToString());
int i = 0;
foreach (string ent in ht.Values)
{   
    string[] name = new string[listbox1.Items.Count];
    for (i = 0; i < listbox1t.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {     
        name[i] = listbox1.Text;
        this.listbox2.Items.Add(name[i]);
    } 
    listbox2.DisplayMember = ht.Values.ToString();
    listbox2.ValueMember = ht.Keys.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DisplayMember` is not what should be displayed, but a name of the property that is evaluated for each object in `Items` collection. So for, for example, objects representing customers it is `FullName` ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx), example inclueded).

`ValueMember` should contain the name of the property uniquely identifying the object, so for example `CustomerId`.

Answer (score 0):

assign a list as a datasource to your first listcontrol:

```
listBoxControl1.Datasource = new List<string>() {"one","two","three","four"};
```

and in the selectedvaluechanged event...

```
var tmp = listBoxControl1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>();
listBoxControl2.datasource = tmp.ToList<string>();
```

should work...

I used a string as an example, you should cast to the class you use instead.
and... assign displayvalue and valuemember in your constructor, no need to do it many times.